# How to translate the SQL query to Laravel Eloquent query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, eloquent-relationship

I'm trying to make a complex query using Laravel Eloquent. I know how to do it using raw SQL query, but I don't have any idea how to do it using Eloquent.
Here is my SQL query, and it works perfectly:

```sql
select *
from students
where exists(select *
             from (select student_movements.id AS sm_id, student_movements.direction, student_movements.deleted_at
                   from student_movements
                            inner join student_student_movements
                                       on student_movements.id = student_student_movements.student_movement_id
                   where students.id = student_student_movements.student_id
                     and student_movements.deleted_at is null
                   order by student_movements.id desc
                   limit 1) as last_sm
             where last_sm.direction = 1 AND last_sm.date >= 5-5-2022
          );
```

My models have many-to-many relation using `student_student_movements` table:

Student

```
    public function studentMovements(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            StudentMovement::class,
            'student_student_movements',
        );
    }
```

StudentMovement

```
    public function students(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Student::class,
            'student_student_movements'
        );
    }
```

My goal is to get all Students, who have the last Movement where direction = 1 and the date of the last Movement >= `$someDate`.
So, my question is: how to translate the SQL query to Eloquent? I saw many similar questions, but they are not helping me.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Try to use eager loading inside the eloquent. Using RAW queries isn't that much problem.

Comment: this could help you https://dev.to/dalelantowork/laravel-8-eloquent-relationships-tutorial-many-to-many-relationship-15a2

Answer (score 0):

Use the whereHas method, then fine tune the sub query inside the closure to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the **whereHas** and **orWhereHas** methods to define
> additional query constraints on your has queries.

There is an example like that in laravel documentation

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
 
// Retrieve posts with at least one comment containing words like code%...
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'code%');
})->get();
 
// Retrieve posts with at least ten comments containing words like code%...
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'code%');
}, '>=', 10)->get();
```

check the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)